# Problems with content of the MBR file

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, files, mbr

I'm trying to look at the content of MBR file.

I save its content to some file, for example `mbr.bin`:

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=mbr.bin bs=512 count=1`

Then I use `file` utility:
`file mbr.bin`. I expect to see information about partitions here.

But all it produces is `mbr.bin: DOS/MBR boot sector`.

If I open `mbr.bin` for example in gedit. The output will look like the following.

[image]

You may notice the `Error` message here.

I actually think there are might be some problems with my MBR file.

By the way, I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: It is a binary file so you need to read it with a binary editor. At an rate reading the file may or may not help you , unless you plan to write your own file from scratch ... What problem are you having ? I suggest you run boot repair.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I expected `file` to give some information about partitions, but it only outputs `mbr.bin: DOS/MBR boot sector`.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I thought it will output some additional text like in this http://docs.gz.ro/linux-read-mbr.html tutorial.

Comment: `fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: From various clues presented in this question, this particular disk probably uses the [Master Boot Record (MBR);](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) however, the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) is more common on modern (~2012 and later) computers. I mention this because the MBR (first sector) of the disk reveals nothing about actual partitions on a GPT disk; you *must* use a partitioning tool like `parted` or `gdisk` on such disks. (Recent versions of `fdisk` will work, too, but older ones are useless on GPT disks.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Could you please [edit] your question to clarify? There are many partition table viewers and editors. Some of them have text-based user interfaces (e. g. `fdisk` and `parted`) or can convert between binary and textual representations (e. g. `sfdisk` and `cfdisk`), if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I expect to see information about partitions here.

Your expectation is too optimistic. :) `file` tells you what kind of file you are looking at. If you want to check the partitions, you might want to do something like:

```
fdisk -l mbr.bin
```

Or maybe:

```
parted -l mbr.bin
```

Now, regarding your attempt with `gedit`, we are talking about a binary file. Of course it won't show up correctly in a text editor. I don't get what you were expecting to see exactly... but if you are interested in the bytes, open it with a hex editor.

See also [Viewing contents of hard drive in binary](https://superuser.com/a/1116687/278831) on Super User.

Comment: I just pointed out it may be some errors with my partition table. Unfortunately, I was right.  `fdisk -l mbr.bin` gives `Failed to read extended partition table (offset=1941149694): Inappropriate ioctl for device
`. Then it has some information file and so-called `Devices`(which looks like partitions; their size, id, etc). What should I do in order to fix partition table?

Comment: If you have an extended partition then you cannot *just* read the MBR. You have to read the whole device with `fdisk`.

Comment: Can you please give me a prompt how to read the whole device with `fdisk`? I was unable to find a command in short time. Also is it legit to delete an extended partition, which contains `Linux Swap Partition`(so I will have to delete `linux-swap` too)?

Comment: `fdisk -l /dev/sda` as usual. The rest are other questions that you can open on the site.

Answer (score 4):

**The MBR is not a plain text file.** The only way you will be able to make any sense whatsoever of it would be to use `hexdump`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda count=1 | hexdump -C
```

Comment: “The only way” Well, saying that `hexdump` is the **only** way seems a bit of a stretch. :)